# How do I prove the anti-symmetry and there is a minimal element for each subset of $\alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> An **ordinal number** is a set $\alpha$ with the following properties:
>
> (a) If $x,y \in \alpha,$ then either $x\in y$, $y\in x$, or $x=y.$
>
> (b)If $y\in \alpha$ and $x\in y$, then $x\in \alpha$.

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal number. For any two numbers $x$ and $y$ of $\alpha$, define $\leq$ on $\alpha$ by $x\leq y$ iff $x=y$ or $x\in y$.

Theorem:-
Let $\alpha$ is an ordinal number. Then $(\alpha,\leq)$ is a well ordered set.

Proof:-

I don't have the doubts in the proof of Reflexivity, Transitivity. I could be able to prove each element is comparable in $\alpha$.

Doubt 1. **anti-symmetric**
 $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$. Our claim is $x=y.$

Case 1 $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ means $x=y$ and $y\in x \implies x\in x$. Which is a paradox. How do I prove the anti-symmetry?

Case 2 $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ means $x=y$ and $y= x \implies x= y$.

Case 3 $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ means $x\in y$ and $y= x \implies x\in x$.

Case 4 $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ means $x\in y$ and $y\in x \implies x= y$.

Also How do I prove there is a minimal elemnt for each subset of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-symmetry may be proven the following way: Let $x, y\in \alpha$ such that $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$. This means that we have
$$
x\in y \text{ or } x = y\\
\text{and}\\
y\in x \text{ or }y = x
$$
So, one possibility is certainly that $x = y$. If $x\neq y$, then that means that we must have $x\in y$ and $y\in x$, which cannot be true (as the set $\{x, y\}$ would violate the axiom of foundation / regularity). This proves anti-symmetry.

As for well-orderedness, take a non-empty subset $S\subseteq \alpha$. By the axiom of foundation, there is an element $x\in S$ such that $x\cap S = \varnothing$. I claim that this $x$ is minimal in $S$.

Assume, for contradiction, that $x$ is not minimal. Then there is a $y\in S$ with $y\leq x, y\neq x$. This means that $y\in x$. But then we have $y\in x\cap S$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You mean  axiom of foundation as Russel's paradox?

Comment: @Mathgeek What do you mean? If you want to argue about sets on a fundamental level, you _have_ to be aware of your axiomatic system. I assumed the ZF axioms, because that's the most common one. The axiom of foundation is one of the ZF axioms, and is specifically needed to avoid sets like $x\in x$, or as in my case, $x\in y, y\in x$. You can do set theory with the ZF axioms except foundation, and in that case $x\in x$ is entirely possible and not paradoxical at all. Particularily, there is no Russel's paradox in sight anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) is accepted in this context.

Then consequently it cannot happen that $x\in x$ so the cases 1 and 3 will not show up.

Also the axiom excludes the situation that $x\in y\in x$ so also case 4 is excluded.

Our conclusion is then that we are dealing with case 2 as was to be shown.

Proved is now that $\leq$ is an anti-symmetric relation on $\alpha$.

---

Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $\alpha$.

According to the axiom this set contains an element $a$ such that all elements of $a$ are *not* elements of $A$.

So if $x\in A$ then we do not have: $x\in a$.

But what we do have is: $x\in a\vee x=a\vee a\in x$.

So what remains is: $x=a\vee a\in x$ or equivalently $a\leq  x$.

This proves that $a$ serves as least element of $A$ in the order $(\alpha,\leq)$.